# Multiplication table structure

Tags: c#, multiplication, tabular

Question about structure of this multiplication table..

How do I make spaces so the output would be like this:

```
      1 X 9 + 2 = 11
     12 X 9 + 3 = 111
    123 X 9 + 4 = 1111
   1234 X 9 + 5 = 11111
  12345 X 9 + 6 = 111111
 123456 X 9 + 7 = 1111111
1234567 X 9 + 8 = 11111111
```

Code:

```
#region MTABLE

int number1 = 1;

for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++)

{
    int number2 = number1 * 9 + i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} + {2} = {3}  ", number1, 9, i, number2);
    number1 = number1 * 10 + i;

    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    Console.Write(" ");
}

Console.ReadKey();

#endregion
```

My code currently outputs:

```
1 x 9 + 2 = 11
  12 x 9 + 3 = 111
   123 x 9 + 4 = 1111
    1234 x 9 + 5 = 11111
     12345 x 9 + 6 = 111111
      123456 x 9 + 7 = 1111111
       1234567 x 9 + 8 = 11111111
```

Comment: So write 9 spaces on the first line, 8 on the next, 7 on the next etc.. hint: How to write an expression to transform i, for each i in [1,2,3,..9] to [9..3,2,1]? That is, write the "f" expression in: `int i2 = f(i);` Alternatively, use a secondary "down" counter variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the inner loop to the beginning of the outer loop and count backwards from 8-i:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 8-i; j >0; j--)
        Console.Write(" ");

    int number2 = number1 * 9 + i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} + {2} = {3}  ", number1, 9, i, number2);
    number1 = number1 * 10 + i;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to make similar for but without this "8 - i" .. also when i tried with "j--" loop never ended

Comment: Well, I've tried my version and the result looks like what you are looking for. Bonus style points: define the 8 as a constant and use that constant instead of repeating the 8 several times in the code

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just want to count down instead of up. You can do that by subtracting i from 8 in the condition.

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 8 - i; j++)
    Console.Write(" ");
```